# Multiple Auto-Embedded videos one always ends up white

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, embed

I have the code here:
    
    function cbfunca(datas){
    var videoRefs = (datas.value.items[0].content);
    var frames = 'http://www.youtube
    nocookie.com/v/'+videoRefs+'?version=3&hl=en_GB&rel=0\"
    type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"560\"
    height=\"349\">';
    var curtextvals = document.getElementById("pumps");
    curtextvals.innerHTML = (frames); 
    }
    
    Video Should Be Here, If you see this, you did something wrong

_id=f261e19584a4dd5cb0a61386b24e80bf&_render=json&_callback=cbfunca">

the second code here:
    
    function cbfunc(data){
    var videoRef = (data.value.items[0].content);
    var frame = 'http://www.youtube-
    nocookie.com/v/'+videoRef+'?version=3&hl=en_GB&rel=0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-
    flash\" width=\"560\" height=\"349\">';
    var curtextval = document.getElementById("pump");
    curtextval.innerHTML = (frame); 
    }
    
    Video Should Be Here, If you see this, you did something wrong

The First one always Doesn't appear? how might i fix this? Sorry the code doesn't seem to come up right here.

Comment: In your code the urls are not the same: the first one is missing a "-". You wrote www.youtubenocookie.com for the first one and www.youtube-nocookie.com for the second.

Comment: @als i did that on accident when i tried to please stackoverflows system by making it code.

Comment: heres the whole code [link](http://pastebin.com/Kz40x8fj)

Comment: To find out how to put code here in your question, see help: "prefix each line with 4 spaces" or use the Ctrl+k after code-text selection. Anyway, i tried the code from your link. There was missing a "/v/", after which it runs and shows 2 videos on the webpage. However, this "/v/" is present in the code above. I'll put the code that works for me in an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code from your link that works for me (it does show 2 videos on the webpage); after adding a "/v/" on the second iframe url.

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="middle" align="center"colspan="2" class="dty"><span class="t">Most Recent Video</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cbfunc(data){
var videoRef = (data.value.items[0].content);
var frame = '<iframe class=\"embeddedvideo\" src=\"http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/'+videoRef+'?version=3&hl=en_GB&rel=0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"560\" height=\"349\"></iframe>';
var curtextval = document.getElementById("pump");
curtextval.innerHTML = (frame); 
}
</script>
<div id="pump">Video Should Be Here, If you see this, you did something wrong</div>
<p>
<script src="http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=35717280d4cd32a61acd1a36f09635c5&_render=json&_callback=cbfunc">
</script>
       </th>







       </tr>    <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="middle" align="center"colspan="2" class="dty"><span class="t">Most Recent Minecraft Video</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cbfunca(datas){
var videoRefs = (datas.value.items[0].content);
var frames = '<iframe class=\"embeddedvideo\" src=\"http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/'+videoRefs+'?version=3&hl=en_GB&rel=0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"560\" height=\"349\"></iframe>';
var curtextvals = document.getElementById("pumps");
curtextvals.innerHTML = (frames); 
}
</script>
<div id="pumps">Video Should Be Here, If you see this, you did something wrong</div>
<p>
<script src="http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=f261e19584a4dd5cb0a61386b24e80bf&_render=json&_callback=cbfunca">
</script>
```

Comment: oh well, thanks for trying, it works some of the time, and not others

Comment: Do you mean that if i run this given sample code a few times , i should see the error ? Then within how many runs should i surely see this error. Or do you run the code with different values for the "_id" parameter ? Then there could be an unexpected results set being returned or none at all. Maybe add a test on the value of videoRef and videoRefs: it must be a string of exactly 11 characters with only letters, numbers, - or _.

Comment: what i mean, is that i can't find out what causes it, but it will work some of the time, and when it doesn't it shows up white, it is not as frequent though anymore.

Comment: It's back :( I can't get it to reliably show the videos... same script.

Comment: I didn't check my messages until today. Running the code today: No data is returned from any http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run